# I am trying to extract tweets from a twitter query on Python using Twython

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I am trying to go through a list of tweets related to a specific search term and trying to extract all the hashtags. I wish to make a python list which includes all the hashtags. I started by using Twython as follows

```
from twython import Twython

api_key = 'xxxx'
api_secret = 'xxxx'
acces_token = 'xxxx'
ak_secret = 'xxxx'


t =  Twython(app_key = api_key, app_secret = api_secret, oauth_token = acces_token,          oauth_token_secret = ak_secret)
search = t.search(q = 'Python', count = 10)

tweets = search['statuses']
hashtags = []
for tweet in tweets:
    b = (tweet['text'],"\n")
    if b.startswith('#'):
        hastags.append(b)
```

It doesn't seem to be working. I get the error that
'tuple object has no attribute startswith'

I am not sure if I am meant to make a list of all the statuses first and extract using the mentioned method. Or it is okay to proceed without making the list of statuses first.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, strings have the startswith attribute and tuples do not.

Change the last three lines to this:

```
b = (tweet['text'])
if b.startswith("#") is True:
    hashtags.append(b)
```

If you really want that line break then it would be:

```
b = (tweet['text'] + "\n")
if b.startswith("#") is True:
    hashtags.append(b)
```

Comment: No problem ... now you just need to accept the answer so it doesn't keep showing up in the list as unanswered.